# What does the UserAgent "LSIE" stand for?

Tags: user-agent

Recently, there are some visits to my site with UserAgent "**Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0; LSIE 1.1.8.4)**". What does the "LSIE" stand for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`LSIE` is an additional information added to the UserAgent string

Usually a part of the UserAgent is used to add additional info about the used browser/machine/factory; LSIE seems to be an additional info added from `BenQ-Siemens` systems.

Answer (score 0):

LSIE stands for "large scale internet extraction," which was program by the government to scrape the internet.

After Snowden's revelations the project's name was changed. I think the new name was "Everest."